# Diffusion Model without Text Prompt?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, gan

I hope I understand diffusion models well enough that this isn't too dumb of a question but...

I'd like to (I think) augment a diffusion model to:

At training time accept CT scan images, then apply an iterative noising schedule to simulate ultrasound noise/image degradation.

Then, at test time, I'd like to input new, low-quality simulated (or real) ultrasound images and have the model output the CT scan/high quality images.

Would a diffusion model be the way to go here? Or would something like a GAN/VAE be more reasonable?